# Jquery mouseover and z-index: what determines which element is on "top"?

Tags: jquery, z-index, mouseover

I am working on a game that calls for a large map.  What I do is set the big 12k x 12k pixel map in the background of a scrollable div (scrollWindow) with a z-index of 1.

Later, an Ajax call returns some JSON data that adds a number of classes (City_Palace) inside of the large background map.  The elements have z-index of 9.

I also have a couple mouseover events set up that do different things based on whether the cursor is over the map in the background or over one of the cities draw on top of it.  However, even though the z-index of the cities is much higher than that of the main window, the event never fires for the city mouseover because the scrollable window is on "top".

What criteria is used for jquery to determine which div is on "top" when it comes to mouse events?  It seems z-index is not it.

Here is some code:

CSS:

```
#scrollWindow {
    width: 1970px;
    height: 900px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border: solid black 3px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

.City_Palace {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-image: url("../Images/City_Palace.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.City_Palace').mouseover(function() {
    alert("city classes on top");
});


$("#scrollWindow").mousemove(function(e){
    alert("scroll window on top");
});
```

Here is how the HTML is generated:

```
<div id="scrollWindow" class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 2105px;">
    <img id="img" src="../Images/fullSizeMap.png">
    <div class="City_Palace" value="coast" style="left: 780px; top: 540px;"></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing that somehow the child-parent relationship is overriding the z-index.  Any suggestions on how I might fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into the dom structure like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="top">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="laterindom"></div>
```

the z-index depends on the layout / style.

elements which are located before other elements are positioned "below" them in z-index herarchy, except you are specifiying z-index for them.

elements "in" another element (like the class="top" element) are are above their parents in the z-index, but the mouseover event will bubble up in dom by default, so if you attach the mouseover event to the "parent" class, your method will be called too, because it bubbles up, even if the "top" element is "above" your "parent" element :)

by the way, you can prevent the event bubbling by calling event.stopPropagation() like this:

```
$(element).mousemove(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //some other code here
});
```

if you now set z-index for the parent to 1, and the z-index for "top" to 9 but the z-index of "laterindom" to 2, the "laterindom" element will be above your "top" even if the "top" element should be higher.. sad, but it is defined like that.

in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/R59Q8/3/ the city is above the scroll window, but the element below the scroll window in dom is above the city, even if the city has z-index 9 and the topmost element only 2.

hope this helps

Comment: I think I understand the theory, so I tried something else around: I attached the mouseover to the #img div instead of the scrollwindow.  This means the they should be at the same level in the DOM.  However, it still doesn't matter whether or not it comes before or after the .City_Palaces, the mouseover for the .City_Palaces never fires.  I've also added the line e.stopPropogation() in the #img mousemove event, no effect.